# file sort in c++ by modification time

Tags: c++, linux, sorting, std

How to sort a file by modification time in C++?

`std::sort` needs a comparison function.
It takes vector as the arguments. I want to sort files based on modification.
Is there already a comparison function or API available that I can use to achieve this?

Comment: Windows? Linux? Mac Os X? Getting file modification date is an OS-specific task. For cross-platformness, check out Boost

Comment: Looking for solution in linux

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use `std::sort` and tell it to use a custom comparison object, like this:

```
#include <algorithm>

std::vector<string> vFileNames;
FileNameModificationDateComparator myComparatorObject;
std::sort (vFileNames.begin(), vFileNames.end(), myComparatorObject);
```

The code for the `FileNameModificationDateComparator` class (feel free to use a shorter name):

```
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h> 
#include <time.h>   

/*
* TODO: This class is OS-specific; you might want to use Pointer-to-Implementation 
* Idiom to hide the OS dependency from clients
*/
struct FileNameModificationDateComparator{
    //Returns true if and only if lhs < rhs
    bool operator() (const std::string& lhs, const std::string& rhs){
        struct stat attribLhs;
        struct stat attribRhs;  //File attribute structs
        stat( lhs.c_str(), &attribLhs);
        stat( rhs.c_str(), &attribRhs); //Get file stats                        
        return attribLhs.st_mtime < attribRhs.st_mtime; //Compare last modification dates
    }
};
```

[stat struct definition here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stat_%28Unix%29), just in case.

**Warning**: I didn't check this code

*UPDATE*: Per comment, this solution can fail if there is an external process modifying the files while sort takes place. It's safer to `stat` all the files first, and then sort them. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74028163/what-will-stdsort-do-if-the-comparison-is-inconsistent-ab-bc-ca) for details on this particular scenario.

*UPDATE 2*: I answered this a very long time ago. Nowadays, if your C++ code needs to interact with the file system and needs to work on multiple OSes, I would strongly advise using [Boost](https://www.boost.org/) to avoid all cross-system headaches.   Remember that you can "trim" Boost to only get the libraries your app needs; there is no need to bundle the whole suite of libraries. This reduces the overhead of using Boost considerably.

Comment: I have verified it with android phone. It works fine

Comment: Warning: this [can crash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74028163/what-will-stdsort-do-if-the-comparison-is-inconsistent-ab-bc-ca) if mtimes are changed by an outside process while the sort is running. It will be both faster and safer to make a list of the times first, and sort it then.

Comment: Great point; I will update the answer