# How does NDK get modified date of a file?

Tags: file, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I am new at Android NDK. Here is a function that gets list of files sort by modified date. I had searched all over this forum, no luck.

Anyone can give me tips about this?

Thanks

Comment: Where is the function? One of the better tips for using the site is: show us the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be a c++ specific problem, please try to use:

```
struct stat attrib;
stat(filePath, &attrib);
char date[10];
strftime(date, 20, "%d-%m-%y", localtime(&(attrib.st_ctime))); 
printf("The file %s was last modified at %s\n", filePath, date);
```

[Found Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10446526/get-last-modified-time-of-file-in-linux)

Then you only have to order your list of files by the `&(attrib.st_ctime)`

`EDIT for second question:`

Use `std::sort` and tell it to use a custom comparison object, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7348347/3286569).

Comment: Great, thanks a lot. However there is new problem coming up. I can get single file's date now. But how can I sort them by date? If I compare their dates, it should cost a long time if there are many files. Is there a simple way to do this?