# What will std::sort do if the comparison is inconsistent? (A<B, B<C, C<A)

Tags: c++, sorting

I need to sort a file list by date. There's [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7337651/file-sort-in-c-by-modification-time) how to do it. It worries me though: it operates on a live filesystem that can change during operation.

The comparison function uses:

```
struct FileNameModificationDateComparator{
    //Returns true if and only if lhs < rhs
    bool operator() (const std::string& lhs, const std::string& rhs){
        struct stat attribLhs;
        struct stat attribRhs;  //File attribute structs
        stat( lhs.c_str(), &attribLhs);
        stat( rhs.c_str(), &attribRhs); //Get file stats                        
        return attribLhs.st_mtime < attribRhs.st_mtime; //Compare last modification dates
    }
};
```

From what I understand, this function can, and will be called multiple times against the same file, comparing it against different files. The file can be modified by external processes while sort is running; one of older files can become the newest in between two comparisons and turn up older than a rather old file, and later newer than one of newest files...

What will `std::sort()` do? I'm fine with some scarce ordering errors in the result. I'm not fine with a crash or a freeze (infinite loop) or other such unpleasantries. Am I safe?

Comment: garbage in, garbage out.  You either need to lock the system so new files can't be added during this time or take a snapshot of the filesystem and sort that.  You can't sort a data set while it is being mutated.

Comment: If the underlying data (like the files) is modified during the sorting, you'll have *undefined behavior* Read all the file-information you need once into a container, then sort referencing this fixed non-modifying container instead.

Comment: I have seen it crash with a poor comparer.

Comment: And if possible please use [`std::filesystem`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem) and its [`status`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/status) function instead.

Comment: Even ignoring UB, I'd prefer to `stat` the files only once, for speed.

Comment: How does any other application you know of handle this?  Maybe simply have a "refresh" option, just like any typical "file manager" application.  User refreshes, the sort looks at the current set of files and sorts those files.  Or how about one that works on a timer -- sort every minute or whatever setting the user chooses?  And in that, you would keep a container of files from the last sort, get the new list, compare if the new list is different than the old list, and if so, then sort.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Freeze the list one way or another (copy, exclusive access, timing, prayer). It's not always possible. I'm fully aware this is not something that should be done if it can be avoided. I wonder what happens if you can't avoid it.

Comment: @SF. Just traverse the list of files using `std::filesystem` -- the files you end up with, that's just the way it is.  Sort that list.  I think you're worrying a bit too much, or trying to over-engineer your solution.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I wish I could. Stuck with C++11 while std::filesystem is since C++17

Comment: Question title looks like trying to sort rocks, papers, and scissors :)

Comment: Anything that needs to keep the list sorted _live_ will still generate the list "normally" but then also handle events directly from the file system such as change notifications, journal entries, _etc_. These are technologies specific to a platform and/or file system. But if you have something like that, you can then update lists as required with relatively low overhead, using whatever algorithm for updating partially-ordered data is most appropriate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As other answers have already said, handing `std::sort` a comparator that doesn't satisfy the *weak strict ordering* requirement and is preserved when called multiple times with the same value will cause undefined behavior.

That doesn't only mean that the range may end up not correctly sorted, it may actually cause more serious problems, not only in theory, but also in practice. A common one is as you already said infinite loops in the algorithm, but it can also introduce crashes or vulnerabilities.

For example (I haven't checked whether other implementations behave similarly) I looked at libstdc++'s `std::sort` implementation, which as part of introsort  uses insertion sort. The insertion sort calls a function `__unguarded_linear_insert`, see [github mirror](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/stl_algo.h#L1827). This function performs a linear search on a range via the comparator without guarding for the end of the range, because the caller is supposed to have already verified that the searched item will fall into the range. If the result of the comparison changes between the guard comparison in the caller and the unguarded linear search, the iterator will be incremented out-of-bounds, which could produce a heap overrun or null dereference or anything else depending on the iterator type.

Demonstration see https://godbolt.org/z/8qajYEad7.

Comment: Thank you. While "an undefined behavior" usually is sufficient, I'm far more fond of answers like yours - ones that tell how exactly that undefined behavior behaves in practice.

Answer (score 5):

> Am I safe?

No.

`std::sort` requires a comparison with *strict weak ordering* and `A<B, B<C, C<A` violates that.

This violation incurs undefined behavior, and in practice, results in some of the worst kinds of undefined behavior.

It should also be noted that any sort algorithm that were written to work on elements that arbitrarily change ordering during the sort would be near-impossible.  At no time would the algorithm know that the entire collection is currently sorted.

Comment: If the comparison is consistently inconsistent ( A<B, B<C, C<A *always*) it's quite likely to get stuck. But if they just occasionally mutate live as in the filesystem example, a plain old Bubblesort will just keep trying until it gets one good pass.

Comment: @SF.: But the list won't be sorted afterwards, because the filesystem can still mutate after the sort. The point is that no algorithm can guarantee sorting if the data or criteria changes, consistently or not.

Comment: @NicolBolas The list will have the obvious sorting errors coming from the mutations, but it will get as close to sorted as it gets, and the algorithm will finish just fine, if taking more time than normally.

Comment: @SF. has valid points here.  From the question: _"I'm fine with some scarce ordering errors in the result"_

Comment: @SF.  *and the algorithm will finish just fine* -- Maybe not.  The issue is that there are debug runtimes that will check if your sort criteria indeed follows a strict-weak-order.  For example, the Visual C++ debug runtime does this -- it does it by calling your sort criteria function twice, the first with a,b compared, and then switched b,a.  If there is an inconsitency, the runtime asserts().  What if your file information for a and b change in between when this check is done?

Comment: @DrewDormann It is not only about wrong orderings in the result. Using such a comparator could also easily introduce (very) rare crashes and/or vulnerabilities, see e.g. the answer I just posted.

Comment: I'm now perfectly aware std::sort will fail in particularly ugly way. My point is an algorithm that can deal with this problem is possible and errors in the result of its operation would be limited to whatever mutations happen during the last pass to the part of data already determined as sorted.

Answer (score 3):

`std::sort()` assumes that the collection is sortable.

Relational algebra defines a set as sortable if:

- it's reflexive, that is, a <= a is true
- antisymmetric, that is: (a <= b and b <= a) <=> a = b
- transitive, that is: (a <= b <= c) => a <= c

See the definition of partial ordering at page 7 of https://web.stanford.edu/class/archive/cs/cs103/cs103.1126/handouts/060%20Relations.pdf

In practice, reflexivity is not a necessary expectation, because, even though a < a is false, but a sorting algorithm may unnecessarily swap equal elements, so, it's strongly advisable to make it reflexive.

Your problem statement says that the relation over your collection is not transitive. But mind you, it is strictly transitive in any moment, the problem is, that during the (short) duration of your sorting algorithm elements may change their values.

This is not a well-defined behavior and in C++ it is undefined behavior.

So, the way I would approach your problem would be to bank on the fact that it's transitive at any time. Also, why would you measure the file sizes each time you compare them? Measuring files is I/O operation and slows down your process. It makes much more sense to measure the files only once, before you sort them, store the results into a collection whose items may change their order, but the values themselves will not change (file1's size will be measured before the algorithm and from there on, until the end of the sort will be unchanged in your set, even if it's no longer true).

The risk involved with this approach is that the result would be deprecated by a few milliseconds that passed since the measurements, a problem that you already specified as being acceptable.

Furthermore, if you need this sorting often, then it might make sense to do a sorting periodically (maybe once every 10 minutes, or the time interval you choose), cache the results and whenever you need the sort, just refer the cache.